# How to use KeyListener in JFrame when there're other components?

Tags: java

I want to do other function when you clicked 'N' button on the keyboard, but there's textfield in there, and the keylistener doesnt' listen. Does anyone have clues?

Here's my code in the frame. when I clicked any button on the keyboard, it doesn't show anything

```
public class TodoFrame extends JFrame implements Colleague, KeyListener {
    private TodoInput todoInput;
    private Todos todos;
    private Actions actions;
    
    private int doneTotal = 0;
    private StateModel state;
    
    private Mediator mediator;
    
    public TodoFrame() {
        this.state = new StateModel();
        this.mediator = new Mediator();

        todoInput = new TodoInput(this.mediator); //<- there's textfield in here
        this.add(todoInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        todos = new Todos(this.mediator, this.state);
        this.add(todos, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        actions = new Actions(this.mediator, this.state);
        this.add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        actions.updateBtn(state);
        
        this.mediator.setAttributes(this, todos);
        mediator.attach(this);
        mediator.attach(actions);
        this.setBackground(Color .BLACK);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void getEvent(Event e) {
        if (e instanceof DoneTotalEvent) {
            DoneTotalEvent de = (DoneTotalEvent) e;
            this.setTitle("Done: " + de.getDoneTotal());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(key); //<- doesn't show anything
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the KeyListener to the JTextField otherwise it never works.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a listener (any type of listener, like `KeyListener` for key events, or `ActionListener` for buttons), you need to add the event listener to the object that will trigger the event. In the case of KeyListener, you need to call the method `addKeyListener(this);` (more specifically, `todoInput.addKeyListener(this);`).

[This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) can help you.